# React Implementation of Pannable and Zoomable element with Draggable Component inside it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

I am trying to build a react application that can create a card component and connect them, and they also can pan and zoom the screen also drag those cards. Like the building window in Figma or Adobe XD. Can anyone suggest to me any popular and effective solution or packages for it. I have been doing some research for a few days now and I could not get a proper solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use drag&drop functionality, basically you need to handle callbacks when drag&drop events happen (onDragStart, onDragEnd, onDragEnter ...), you get data from the event parameter. When something is dropped, you update the state accordingly (add/remove item from list), and render them with map function. Some sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactdrag-and-drop-iq89y?file=/src/components/TaskList.jsx